# Rear Hub Axle Appears Bent – Causes and Repair Strategy

Tags: repair, hub

I had my rear wheel off of the bike noticed that as I spin the axle it appears to be bent – the freewheel end of axle, for lack of a better way to describe it, orbits the centerline of the axle.

First, I'd like to know if there are typically causes – things I should check in addition to repairing the axle.

Second, what should I be looking for to determine if a repair is viable? Could there be damage to the races in the hub? Are there better or worse grades of axle?

It is a 6-speed, quick release (hollow) axle, the hub brand appears to be Quango (marked on the bearing cap/seal) threaded for a freewheel (not a freehub).

Comment: there are numerous existing questions about [bent axles](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=bent+axle) so I strongly suspect this is a dupe. [Perhaps this](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16584/cause-of-spalled-cones)?

Comment: This: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/24416/reoccurring-bent-axles-any-reasons-or-upgrades?rq=1

Comment: It's actually not unusual for the sprocket cluster to appear to "wobble" a bit (a millimeter or so) as it's rotated on the hub.  This usually isn't a problem.  If the entire hub wobbles on the axle as it turns that's a problem (but oddly one you generally wouldn't notice with the wheel on the bike).

Comment: The question starts with "I had my rear wheel off of the bike" so I would guess the wheel was not on the bike. The next part is spinning the axle, something that you can't do with the wheel on bike.